# Streamable direct link to video

Tags: html, video

I have found a way to upload a video to Streamable and get the direct mp4 link, like this:

```
//cdn-e2.streamable.com/video/mp4/tixqy.mp4?token=1505403348_9e5080919f470b957da5774b600351c36a9d9d94
```

Now the problem is that after a while, I don't know the exact period, the link stops working, and needs to be refreshed. I think that is due to the token that is attached to it.

Now I am wondering is there a possibility to make this work indefinitely? Because I need the direct Mp4 link to the HTML5 video player work.

Anyone has an idea?

Comment: Streamable provide the hosting/streaming for you but only support playback in their branded player. If you want your own player then you'll probably need to host the video yourself, either the mp4 file on Azure or S3 or your website host, or using a service like Ooyala or Azure Media Services

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it asking about circumventing a services controls

Comment: Ok I asked for closing as well, cause illegality.

Comment: Why not generate a new link after old one is expired? Have you tried doing that?

Comment: No haven't tried that. How do you do that?